# Connection Reset While Opening SSL Connection to Hosted Exchange

Tags: ssl

My firm has hosted exchange (2003) that can be accessed using outlook or https which has worked for years.  Last Friday night it appears that all Vista and Windows 7 machines began resetting the ssl connection.  XP machines seem ok.

We are able to ping, tracert and telnet -80 to the hosted exchange machine. Our firewall consultant ran packet capture and reviewed the rules to verify traffic is getting in and out of the lan.

I've run wireshark on a client experiencing this problem;  there are 23 frames from beginning to reset.  I can follow the port selection, encrypted handshake, etc, and eventually the RST.

Why is the RST being sent?  I see errors but I'm not sure which are significant.  I see incorrect header checksums, a change cipher spec, a handful of [TCP Retransmission][TCP segment of a reassembled PDU] info records.

Another part of the conversation I don't understand is between out gateway and the client; a "Redirect (Redirect for network)" message using ICMP.

How can you figure out what's causing the RST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ISP was dropping packets.  No explanation provided.